# Magento 2.1 - Having problems with customer login

Tags: error, magento-2.1, login

All of a sudden the customers on my Magento webshop can't login (http://www.healthxl.eu), get confirmation mail or reset password... Also, I noticed that when I tried logging in with a wrong password it just gave me the error (see below).
I tried rolling back a backup I made last week but even this doesn't work.
The error messages:

> An unspecified error occurred. Please contact us for assistance. We're unable to send the password reset email.

---

Sorry for the not so clear question I asked there. However, after updating my Magento install from 2.1 to 2.1.2 the problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because of server space issues. This has happened with me once. Check the server's free space percent

Comment: This issue was resolved after updating. Also, my server had more than enough free space at the time of this issue. Anyway, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: oh . thats great.